# ANTLR4 parsing does not work for repeated text

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I had been successfully parsed below file information until line "To be finalized..." with given grammar. But once we are receiving more data after "To be finalized..." the parser is skipping 1-3 record and in output gives me first header and last 2 records(4-5).

**Question:** How to change the grammar, to be able to have all the data parsed?
*Highly appreciate you in-light on below problem:*

**Parsing text:**(each RECORD here as will be a Map in Java)

```
+++    AV_AW_GER_1111_SpringShop        2017-10-09 12:00:00
O&M    #58513
%%/*123456*/FUN TEST:REC=ALL,SD=2017&10&02,ST=03&01&01,CLRSD=2017&10&09,CLRST=08&10&00;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded

1RECORD  11111       Creat     Warning         KRAN      14758    Signaling
     Sync serial No.  =  121212
          Record name  =  Cell PCI Conflict
   Record raised time  =  2017-11-14 12:15:41
       Place info  =  Local Cell ID=1, Cell Name=AO_5655_56551_L1_B, eNodeB ID=15655, Cell ID=1, NB-IoT Cell Flag=FALSE

2RECORD  22222       Creat     Major           KRAN      52896    Environment
     Sync serial No.  =  231123
          Record name  =  Intruder Record
   Record raised time  =  2017-11-14 13:00:09
       Place info  =  Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=0, Slot No.=19, Port No.=2, Board Type=UPEU

3RECORD  33333       Creat     Major           KRAN      36369    Environment
     Sync serial No.  =  340434
          Record name  =  Intruder Record
   Record raised time  =  2017-11-14 12:58:40
       Place info  =  Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=0, Slot No.=19, Port No.=2, Board Type=UPEU
(Number of results = 3)

To be finalized...

---    END

+++    QW_ER_TY_2222_SpringPool       2017-11-20 13:29:34
O&M    #89874
%%/*012567*/FUN TEST:REC=ALL,SD=2017&10&02,ST=03&01&01,CLRSD=2017&10&09,CLRST=08&10&00;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded

4RECORD  55555       Creat     Warning         KRAN      14736    Signaling
     Sync serial No.  =  45585
          Record name  =  Cell PCI Conflict
   Record raised time  =  2017-11-14 12:15:41
       Place info  =  Local Cell ID=1, PCI Value=408, Conflict Type=Confusion, NB-IoT Cell Flag=FALSE 
       Result type  =  Normally cleared

5RECORD  44444       Creat     Major           KRAN      65137    Environment
     Sync serial No.  =  99999
          Record name  =  Intruder Record
   Record raised time  =  2017-11-14 12:58:40
       Place info  =  Cabinet No.=0, Subrack No.=0, Slot No.=19, Port No.=2, Board Type=UPEU
        Result type  =  Normally cleared
(Number of results = 2)

2 reports in total

---    END
```

**grammar:**

```
rspAlarm:
      alarmResponse alarmResponse1 EOF;
alarmResponse:
   header recordAlarm+ (COMPLEX_FLAG EOL)? TERMINATOR EOL;
alarmResponse1:
      header recordAlarm+ TERMINATOR EOL;
recordAlarm:
     completionStatus|(title SPACE* EOL)|(SPACE* keyValue '=' SPACE* value EOL)|TOTAL|EOL ;
header:
   connectInfo server_code FUNCTION EOL responseIdentification;
connectInfo:
     '+++' SPACE+ STRING (SPACE STRING|NUMBER)? SPACE+ timeStamp EOL*;
timeStamp:
    DATE EOL;
server_code:
    'O&M' SPACE+ HUSH NUMBER+ EOL;
responseIdentification:
        'RETCODE' SPACE '=' SPACE codeStatus SPACE+ completionStatus;
codeStatus:
    NUMBER;
completionStatus:
    COMPLETION_CODE EOL;
title:
    (STRING|NUMBER) (SPACE+ (STRING|NUMBER))*;
keyValue:
    ((STRING|NUMBER) SPACE*)+;
value:
     ( (STRING|NUMBER|DATE|HUSH) SPACE*)+;

NUMBER:('-')?[0-9]+;
DATE:NUMBER+'-'NUMBER+'-'NUMBER+SPACE+NUMBER+':'NUMBER+':'NUMBER+;
STRING:[a-zA-Z0-9\-\'\&\_\@\=\.\:\,\(\)\/]+;
FUNCTION:[\%][\%](.*)[\%][\%];
COMPLETION_CODE:('Success'|'Operation succeeded.'|'No record exists'|'Invalid command,it is inexecutable.'|) EOL;
TOTAL:'(Number of results = ' NUMBER ')';
COMPLEX_FLAG:('To be finalized...');
TERMINATOR :('---    END');
DASH:[\-]+;
PLUS:[\+][\+][\+];
EOL:'\r'?'\n';
SPACE:' ';
HUSH:[\#];
WS:('\t'|'\n'|'\r')->skip;
```

**Output:**

```
+++    AV_AW_GER_1111_SpringShop        2017-10-09 12:00:00
O&M    #58513
%%/*123456*/FUN TEST:REC=ALL,SD=2017&10&02,ST=03&01&01,CLRSD=2017&10&09,CLRST=08&10&00;%%
RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded

And Record 4 and 5 + details after.
```

The parser is skippinig Record 1-3, but all the file had been read.

Comment: Using ANTLR 4.6 there are 9 `invalid escape sequence` errors in `STRING`,  `FUNCTION` etc. Is the posted grammar working for you ?

Comment: Yeah, it's work for me, @BernardK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the token "FUNCTION" consumes all the record, in your case you should use a non-greedy rule, try the following:

```
FUNCTION:[\%][\%](.*?)[\%][\%];
```

note the question mark

Comment: Thank you, @gtosto, it's worked perfectly! Your correction affected the whole structure. The greedy rule was consuming all the rows until its met the last %%.